# Carrierwave + Fog: Use DNS name instead of S3 host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I have a Carrierwave file that's uploaded to `some/reasonable/path.ext` on some `s3-bucket`. When I get the URL for that file, I get something like `https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket/some/reasonable/path.ext`.

I've also got `some.host.com` pointing to that bucket. Is there a built-in way to have Carreirwave return, as the URL for a file, something like `https://some.host.com/some/reasonable/path.ext` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set this as a config option. I think it might just be `asset_host: "https://some.host.com"` for your example.

Comment: Hmm. Think `def asset_host; ...; end` would work in the Uploader?